# MS Access does not show Name of project owner when linked to Sharepoint lists

Tags: list, microsoft-access

I am connecting to Sharepoint through MS Access 2003 and the lists are displayed in Access as linked tables. Everything is fine till here. The list when accessed in Sharepoint site (in browser) shows the name of the project owner e.g.LastName, FirstName but the same field is not shown when the linked Sharepoint list is viewed in Access. The data type of that field in sharepoint is Person and looks up the name through Active Directory.

I am looking for some more info on why the name field does not show up in Access linked table?

Answer (score 1):

You might try creating a new query off your linked table and you should see all fields available. For some reason the table view leaves out a lot of fields, probably due to a property setting on the field.